# Extjs 4 : Custom form creation

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

How to get following layout in extjs 4.1.3??

[image: form Layout]

I want checkbox to attach next to textbox.
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a `FieldContainer` with an `hbox` layout.  See the docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldContainer

```
{
    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
    fieldLabel: 'lamp failed',

    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield'
    }, {
        xtype: 'checkbox'
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Partially it works, but, How to put label/heading on top of checkBox?? It distorts view.

Comment: There won't be a "clean" way to do that, you will just need to finagle a dom element in there somewhere with your label.  You can try adding a `fieldLabel` with `labelAlign: 'top'` to your `checkbox` on the top row, and playing with the styles of that a bit.

Comment: I do not have access to jsfiddle, but like my prior comment said, I did not suspect that my suggestion would work exactly as you needed, but that you will have to play around with it a bit.  You could also try inserting a dom fragment manually.  Hopefully I at least answered your original question and put you on the right track.